# How to extract price from Amazon Url without Amazon API

Tags: php, yii, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to load html file from a Amazon URL to extract the product price using a simple php function on Yii.
I started to get the entire file with php function `file_get_contents`, and than extract only the price from my html file with DOM.

I'm using a DOM parser to read the HTML file. It has convenient functions to read the tags of a html file. This is the parser:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

The URL that php analyze can be of amazon.com, amazon.co.uk, amazon.it, etc. In the future this feature will be used also to analyze other url different from Amazon.

I created a simple function, that from a URL, extract the price, here it is:

```
public function findAmazonPriceFromUrl($url) {
    Yii::import('ext.HtmlDOMParser.*');
    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $item = $html->getElementsById('actualPriceValue');
    if ($item) {
        $price = $item[0]->firstChild()->innertext;
    } else {
        $item = $html->getElementsById('current-price');
        $price = $item[0]->innertext;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

The `file_get_html` function is the following:

```
function file_get_html($url) {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        return false;
    }
$dom->load($contents);
return $dom;
```

}

I noticed that after a few request (various links), I always get an error from the server (Error 500). I checked my apache log file, but everything is good.

Amazon could block my requests after certain time? How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: How many times a second are you requesting their pages?

Comment: Youj could add another server that you use to query. First tryu checking the contents of the page when the 500 error occurs. Also, consider using their product search api

Comment: Well if you're scrapping their pages in a high frequency they could possible block you, the solution for that is using proxies or slowing your requests

Comment: The request is made by the user when create a new post. He put a link of a product and the data are extracted. So requests are made ​​only to the creation of the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and this is my fix: I run script again  if image is not parsed. image is parsed first in my php script so I check if it works and amazon gives information. I hope it helps.

```
if($html->find('#main-image')) {    
   foreach($html->find('#main-image') as $e) {
      echo '<span href="'. $e->src . '" class="imgblock parseimg">
               <img src="'. $e->src . '" class="resultimg" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'">
            </span>
            <input type="hidden" name="my-item-img" value="'. $e->src . '" />';
   }
} else {
   gethtml($url,$domain);
   die;
}
```

Comment: after image check and sending request again (when it's not parsed) you don't need to type else...gethtml... for other objects (price, size...) because if image is parsed it means amazon gives whole page and there is nothing to worry about